# Is there a PHP port of the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, encryption-symmetric

Is there a php implementation of the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a port of this specific library, but you can use [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) and [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) and [openssl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) extensions to achieve same results.

Comment: As I expected, just making sure I don't reinvent the wheel.